# How to Convert Figma Design to Angular Code?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, figma

I'm currently working on a project where I need to convert a Figma design into Angular code. I've been trying to find a tutorial or guide that can help me with this process, but I haven't had much luck so far.

The design in Figma includes various components, layouts, and styles, and I want to ensure that I can accurately translate it into a functional Angular application. I have a basic understanding of HTML, CSS, and Angular, but I'm not sure about the best practices for integrating a Figma design.

How can this be done?

Comment: Figma isn't going to create Angular code for you. You use Figma to design something and then you use that design to create HTML/CSS components.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no "tool" to do it - you need to do it by yourself.

See - Figma is only for design - you need to decide what is the structure of your application - what is the hierarchy of the components, and what component you will create once and reuse - All of this has no connection to Figma.
you are the programmer so you need to make sure you don't repeat yourself ( Figma code is repeated on all pages )

Answer (score -1):

Figma is available only for designs, You can see all nits and bits of particular webpage design in figma, but you will have to code it in HTML/CSS & Angular.

Apart from this, I know about few tools which can help you to create HTML & CSS from figma, I have not used them but you can try let everyone know that they worked or not.
Following are the links:

https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1128731099343788397/Figma-to-HTML-
and-CSS
https://www.locofy.ai/convert/figma-to-html-css
https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/851183094275736358/Figma-to-HTML

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it out yet but Refer https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1315333447429498897

With Figmular you can:

Convert components from Figma to Angular

Components from Figma can be exported to Angular components that include HTML, CSS, and TypeScript code
When one Figma component uses instances of other components, those other components will be properly exported and referenced with parameters
Even if a Figma component has multiple variants with different properties, it will be exported as a single Angular component with visibility (*ngIf) and class (ngClass) conditions

Generate Angular components with the usage of Angular Material

If a project is built using Material Design, Figma components can be configured as components from Angular Material. So instead of generating a new code, they will just reference existing components from the Angular Material library
Angular Material components have parameters like color, label, type, or others, so Figmular allows to customize their values by reading attributes from the Figma component using Figmular’s Figma Fields. For example, the Figma property ‘Display Text’ can be configured to be a button’s label, or the property ‘Type’ can set one of the button types (mat-button, mat-raised-button, mat-stroked-button, etc.)
… and actually, the Figma designs do not really need to visually match the Material Design for Figmular to work. Any hand-drawn sketch or a rectangle can be configured as an Angular Material component!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).